# dotLottie react-player source map errors

Tags: reactjs, npm, lottie

### I am trying to implement dotLottie with my ReactJS application.

Here are the logs when using the `@dotlottie/react-player` package with `npm`:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@dotlottie/common/dist/chunk-DCAKKOYV.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '(root dir)\SeaSource\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+copy@0.1.3\node_modules\@rgba-image\copy\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '(root dir)\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+copy@0.1.3\node_modules\@rgba-image\copy\src\index.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@dotlottie/common/dist/chunk-DCAKKOYV.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '(root dir)\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+create-image@0.1.1\node_modules\@rgba-image\create-image\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '(root dir)\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+create-image@0.1.1\node_modules\@rgba-image\create-image\src\index.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@dotlottie/common/dist/chunk-DCAKKOYV.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '(root dir)\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+lanczos@0.1.1\node_modules\@rgba-image\lanczos\src\convolve.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '(root dir)\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+lanczos@0.1.1\node_modules\@rgba-image\lanczos\src\convolve.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@dotlottie/common/dist/chunk-DCAKKOYV.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '(root dir)\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+lanczos@0.1.1\node_modules\@rgba-image\lanczos\src\filters.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '(root dir)\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+lanczos@0.1.1\node_modules\@rgba-image\lanczos\src\filters.ts'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@dotlottie/common/dist/chunk-DCAKKOYV.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '(root\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+lanczos@0.1.1\node_modules\@rgba-image\lanczos\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '(root dir)\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@dotlottie+dotlottie-js@0.7.0\node_modules\node_modules\.pnpm\@rgba-image+lanczos@0.1.1\node_modules\@rgba-image\lanczos\src\index.ts'
```

I can see that for some reason, the `.pnpm` folder is referenced, but I am using `npm`.

Here is the *component code*:

```js
import { DotLottiePlayer } from '@dotlottie/react-player';
import '@dotlottie/react-player/dist/index.css';

const SplashScreen = ({ isSolar }) => {
  return (
    <div className="center-div full">
      <div className="splash-img">
        <DotLottiePlayer
          src="./assets/the.lottie"
          autoplay
          loop
          speed={2.5}
        >
        </DotLottiePlayer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SplashScreen;
```